# Redirect to another route with a named outlet

Tags: angular

I have, in my application, two components named: "documents-list" and "document-upload", with the defined route.

```
{ path: "documents", component: DocumentsComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
{ canActivate: UploadRedirectionGuard], component: DocumentsComponent, path: "documents/upload" },
```

Unfortunately, as an analyst request, I have to redirect the documents/upload?parameter to documents?parameter. I was previously just redirecting and defining a variable in my service to know if I had to open the modal on my documents upload, or not.

Now that I have switch to named outlet to handle the modal, I would like to simplify this and avoid using the service for that. This is now my code

```
public canActivate(): boolean {
    this.router.navigate(["documents", { outlets: { modal: "upload" }}], { preserveQueryParams: true });
    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately, it gaves me an error.

```
 Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'documents'
```

I don't really understand why it's not working since the route documents is rightly defined in my router module.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your defined route:

```
{ path: "documents", component: DocumentsComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
{ canActivate: UploadRedirectionGuard, component: DocumentsComponent, path: "documents/upload" }
```

I removed the `]` from your code (`{canActivate: UploadRedirectionGuard], ...`.

Comment: Actually my real code is `canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard, UploadRedirectionGuard]` also, passing a single component or an array of component does not change the behavior. Thanks anyway.